# Error in Magento Test Automation Framework (MTAF)

Tags: magento-1.7, mtaf

I have installed magento test Automation framework in local machine as below reference PDF.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/download/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf

All the installation setup has completed as per the reference.

After that i have added my project to netbeans. When i try to add the project in netbeans it seems error.

Below is the error message, which is i got from netbeans.

```
magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\attribute\js.phtml
```

[image]

[image]

This is my first try of Magento test automation tools. i don't know what was went to wrong.

Any help my appreciation.

Comment: The code looks correct. I think netbeans is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try changing a bit the directory structure

From

```
magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\attribute\js.phtml
```

To

```
magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\template\catalog\product\attribute\js.phtml
```

In my experience, Magento directory structure changes across its versions.